# Hill equation with inhibition and activation

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

The Hill equation for an activating enzymatic interaction with cooperative multiplicity $n$ is

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm dt} = V_\mathrm{max}\frac{[\ce{S}]^n}{K_\ce{S} + [\ce{S}]^n}\tag{1}$$

and for an inhibitory interaction

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm dt} = V_\mathrm{max}\frac{K_\ce{I}}{K_\ce{I} + [\ce{I}]^m}\tag{2}$$

What would the equation be for competing activating and inhibiting compounds $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{I},$ respectively?

My sort of ansatz is that it would be of the form

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm dt} = V_\mathrm{max} \frac{c_\ce{S}[\ce{S}]^n}{K_\ce{SI} + c_\ce{S}[\ce{S}]^n + c_\ce{I}[\ce{I}]^m}\tag{3}$$

I spent about an hour trying to derive the actual answer, but I'm no expert in physical chemistry/biochemistry and increasingly have the sense I should turn to someone who is.

Comment: What type of inhibition (competitive or otherwise) are you interested in? What do you mean by "roughly" in the context of the Hill equations? Hill-ish? Are the $K$s the same?

Comment: @KarstenTheis Let's go with non-competitive inhibition for simplicity's sake, though if there exist modifications for competitive and uncompetitive inhibition I'd be interested in those as well. The Ks are not the same, and I definitely should have been clearer about that. I say "roughly" because I've absorbed the $K_i$ from the canonical form of the inhibition equation into $V_{max}$ in the numerator of the inhibition equation.

Comment: I also believe it would be more accurate to have some constants $c_i$ and $c_s$ to determine the proportional binding strengths of each compound. In the first two equations those could simply be absorbed into K, but in the third equation they might be important.

Comment: Could you edit the question to incorporate the information in the comments? And maybe use two different subscripts for the two different Ks?

Comment: Should all be clearer now. Apologies on the original imprecision. I'm a physicist by training, and I suppose that preference for rough approximations slipped in.

Comment: Equation 2 has a weird limit for [I] = 0. It should be Vmax, but it is Vmax/Ki.

Comment: As mentioned in my earlier comment, I had absorbed a $K_I$ into the $V_{max}$ for that equation to simplify it. You just get a new effective $V_{max}$ when you divide. I understand the units have to be modified slightly to account for that, but it's quite simple. Regardless, I'll add a $K_I$ to the numerator if that's a sticking point. I've also removed the comments about the equations "roughly" being correct, since I now give the exact Hill equations. This was essentially what I meant about "rough" correctness originally. The equations had the right form all along, up to constant factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mechanism of cooperative enzyme activity**

The easiest way to explain cooperativity is the example of hemoglobin, where four nearly identical subunits switch cooperatively between two states T and R of different binding affinity. When no ligand (L) is bound, hemoglobin is in the T state; once at least one ligand is bound, it is predominately in the R state.

$$\ce{T4 + 4 L <=> R_4L + 3 L <=> R4L + 3 L <=> R4L2 + 2 L <=> R_4L3 + L <=> R4L4}$$

The states with 1-3 ligands are less populated (because the R state has higher affinity for the ligand L thant the T state), and we will ignore them:

$$\ce{T4 + 4 L <=> R4L4}$$

From this, you can write the law of mass action and the binding isotherms.

If we apply this to an enzyme with a Hill coefficient of $n$, and call the active state of the enzyme E and the inactive state F, we would have the equilibrium:

$$\ce{F_n + nS<=> E_nS_n}$$

For sufficiently high concentration of substrate S, all enzyme would be in complex with substrate, leading to a rate of $v_\text{max}$.

**Mechanism of cooperative inhibition**

In the OP's question, the Hill coefficient for inhibition $m$ is different from that for enzyme activity ($n$). So we could have a regulatory protein with $m$ subunits attached to the enzyme. It binds cooperatively to inhibitor, which allosterically affects enzyme activity. The regulatory protein would also have two states, T and R, either free or bound to $m$ inhibitors:

$$\ce{ T_m + m I <=> R_mI_m}$$

When the allosteric inhibitor is bound to ligand (i.e. in the R state), the enzyme lacks activity.

**Combination of the two**

Only a certain fraction of enzyme is bound to substrate, and only a certain fraction of enzyme-bound substrate is not inhibited by the regulatory protein. For this scenario, the enzyme activity is $v_\text{max}$ times those two fractions.

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm dt} = v_\mathrm{max}\frac{[\ce{S}]^n}{K_S + [\ce{S}]^n} \cdot \frac{K_I}{K_I + [\ce{I}]^m}\tag{2}$$

**What happens when there is competitive inhibition?**

It gets more complicated. Will the inhibitor also cause a switch in the enzymes conformation? In which direction? For the simpler (non-cooperative) Michaelis Menten model, a competitive inhibitor changes the apparent affinity of enzyme to ligand in a concentration-dependent manner (the enzyme partitions between free, ligand-bound and inhibitor-bound state). For the cooperative case, you would have to decide whether mixed states (such as $\ce{ES2I2}$) are populated; if they are, they would contribute to product formation, but less than $\ce{ES4}$ because not all active sites are turning over substrate.